# using Redis in each Microservices

Tags: docker-compose, redis

I'm beginner to docker, I tried to build up my microservice application with docker, and  both of these services uses Redis as second database (I'm trying to Run Redis on localhost for both Microservices) but couldn't figure it out how to connect 2 Microservices to local Redis. Here's my docker-compose file

**docker-compose**

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  auth-service:
    build: 
      context: auth-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    image: auth-service:latest
    env_file:
      - /Users/ekutlugun/Desktop/hapi/auth-service/.env
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - '8090:8000'
    networks:
      - redis-net
    depends_on:
      - redis
  
  product-service:
    build: 
      context: product-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: product-service:latest
    env_file:
      - /Users/ekutlugun/Desktop/hapi/product-service/.env
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports: 
      - '8080:8000'
    networks:
      - redis-net
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis
    networks:
      - redis-net
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

networks:
  redis-net:

volumes:
  redis-data:
```

**Error**

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
auth-service_1     |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
auth-service_1     |   errno: -111,
auth-service_1     |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
auth-service_1     |   syscall: 'connect',
auth-service_1     |   address: '127.0.0.1',
auth-service_1     |   port: 6379
auth-service_1     | }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose file declares:

```
hostname: redis
```

and `redis` is what you need to use to connect to the Redis container, instead of `127.0.0.1`.

For most of the clients `127.0.0.1` is a default value for the host, so you have to explicitly specify it. For example for node.js:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient({
    host: 'redis',
    port: 6379
});
```

Comment: okay this way I'm not getting error while running code but if I want to make caching operation from  Redis functions I get error hence im not getting any errors when I run on my local device.

Comment: What errors are these?